# event detection: get row per event

Tags: r

I have an irregularly spaced time series in a data.frame.
How can I obtain one row per event, for the maximum value in each event? 
(not just the maximum value per event.)

Events are defined as distinct if they are more than a certain time apart, say three days.
Here's some fake data to play around with:

```
set.seed(42)
x <- data.frame(date=as.Date("2017-08-01")+cumsum(ceiling(rexp(200, rate=0.2))),
                value=round(cumsum(rnorm(200, sd=8)))+500)
plot(x, type="o", pch=16, cex=0.6, las=1)
head(x, 20)
```

Comment: I don't understand what happened... Do you need help? Did you post it so you can answer it? You need a different method? ... Basically...what do you need?

Comment: This was a self-answer (https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). I guess I could have made that clearer. However, there may be better approaches, so those would be welcome.

Comment: What is the question that was answered?

Comment: Sorry, I did a bad job on this one... edited it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

```
# Time differences between observations:
x$diff <- c(0, as.numeric(diff(x$date)) )
# distinct event if more than 3 days apart:
x$event <- cumsum(x$diff>3) 
# simply get maximum value per event:
tapply(x$value, x$event, max, na.rm=TRUE)

# Get one observation row per event (the maximum):
x$max <- unlist(tapply(x$value, x$event, FUN=function(v){
  out <- rep(0, length(v))
  out[which.max(v)] <- 1 # select first maximum value if there are ties
  out
  }))

head(x, 20) 

# independent event maxima rows:
x[x$max==1, 1:2]
```

Hourly time differences can be obtained like this:

```
diffs <- as.difftime(diff(x$date))
units(diffs) <- "hours"
diffs <- as.numeric(diffs)
```